# Change path JRXML in Java

Tags: java, exception, jasper-reports

In My Java app, i have structure like this,

> - sip
>
>   - build
>   - dist
>   - nbproject
>   - src
>
>     - sip
>
>       - Form.java
>       - schedule.jrxml
>   - test

And this my code to load jrxml in Form.java

```
try{
        //String schedule_all ="E:\\My Data\\Tugas Akhir\\repos\\sip\\src\\sip\\jadwal.jrxml";
        InputStream file = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/sip/schedule.jrxml");
        JasperReport jr= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(file);
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,con);
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp,false);
        jv.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error show Document");
        tambah_log(e.toString());
    }
```

I Want to replace this path(E:\My Data\Tugas Akhir\repos\sip\src\sip\jadwal.jrxml";)

to my local project path like this ("/sip/jadwal.jrxml").

but i got this error

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
>   java.net.MalformedURLException

Any Idea? Because i want deploy my system to another computer. And i wont configure its path again.

**FIXED**
I change My Code like this.

```
InputStream file = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/sip/jadwal.jrxml");
        JasperReport jr= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(System.getProperties().getProperty("java.class.path").split(";")[System.getProperties().getProperty("java.class.path").split(";").length - 1]+"\\sip\\jadwal.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,con);
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp,false);
        jv.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getResourceAsStream("/sip/schedule.jrxml");` call doesn't accept that type of "URL"

Check the documentation, if its a local file it probably wants "file:///C:/path/to/whereever/sip/schedule.jrxml"

Or you could see the solution posted here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/620656?start=0&tstart=0

Or better yet here

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/62863-how-to-use-getresourceasstream-to-get-a-file-stream

Comment: i change my code like this. >> JasperReport jr= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(System.getProperties().getProperty("java.class.path").split(";")[System.getProperties().getProperty(" java.class.path").split(";").length - 1] + file);  << And its return null pointer

Comment: why are you calling split?

Answer (score 0):

In windows operating systems java accepts the drive having the os installation as root directory. If you put your /sip directory to that drive, for example (and generally) to C drive. Then you can reach it as

`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/sip/schedule.jrxml");` .

Putting the schedule.jrxml to a package or to a resource folder of the project is a better practice though, because in this case you may install it anywhere you want.

Comment: probably not the best idea to have 2 sip directories either.

Comment: one is for code and one is for the other resources, it is reasonable and os independent.